# Command "ember server" from Ember CLI exits immediately

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

After setting up new development environment I ran into issue with starting the ember server.

I've installed the npm and bower packages, and this is what happens when I run the server in console (it quits immediately after outputting "Serving on..."):

```
➜  project git:(master) ember s      
version: 0.0.28
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
➜  project git:(master)
```

No error message, and the last exit status is surprisingly 0.

If I run *npm start* instead, the ember server starts serving (does not exit like with *ember server*) but after running the app in browser, I experience JavaScript type errors in ember metal-module.

What could be the possible reasons for this behaviour? Is there some error log output that I could check? I'm using Ember Canary and edge Ember CLI.

Comment: Sorry... you're running cli 0.0.28? is that correct?

Comment: That is definitely not edge ember cli.  Can you upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with an app running with `ember-cli 0.0.27`. There was no chance of upgrade so I was stuck with that. I use node version manager and the version of node that I was using was `0.12.0.` When I switched back to node `0.10.32` `ember s` worked as expected.